# Delete one field based on a different field search results

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to delete an unnecessary link based on the results from  a different field, i.e., if the "size" field is NULL (no attachment) then delete the folder link in another field.  I've included a link to help make sense of my question along with the pitiful attempt I've made so far :-).

```
// Check if a file has been uploaded
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {

  // Connect to the database
  $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'ticket_db');
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());\
  }

  // Query for blank attachment link
  $query = "DELETE FROM ('ticket_table') filepath WHERE (size is NULL)";

  // Execute the query
  $query = $dbLink->query($query);
}
```

[Link to screenshot of database tables](http://www.moxleycomputers.com/images/database.png)

Thank you,
Doug

Comment: `DELETE FROM ('ticket_table')` is failing for a few reasons. Check for errors and you'll see what pops up. The whole thing's failing really, *ever so silently*.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  I am running phpMyAdmin and I am having trouble even finding an error log, Grrr!

Answer (score 0):

You should not enclose a table name in quote ( but eventualli if the name contains spechia char or word you can use backticks)

```
 "DELETE FROM ticket_table filepath WHERE size is NULL";
```

And don't use unuseful ()

or

```
   "DELETE FROM `ticket_table` filepath WHERE `size` is NULL";
```

Comment: Hi scaisEdge,  There are no log errors as the command executes fine.  Maybe instead of deleting the upload/ entry it would be easier to replace upload/ with nothing if the condition is met?  I'm very new to mysql and php but I'm relentless and love using it.  Thank you very much for your suggestion!  Oh BTW, the command executes fine but the upload/ entry is still present.

Comment: Oh yeah, good point but it's failing to remove the string upload/.  I am sure I'm missing a field in my DELETE string.  I've been stuck on this for a day and it's kicking my butt :-).  Thank you again for your support!